# Why does sbt 1.0.2 hang after compilation?

Tags: scala, sbt

I have installed `sbt 1.0.2` and tried building the "hello project", but it hangs after done compilation.

I waited for 2 hours and it does not complete. what am I missing here?

```
HOSTPC:IdeaProjects XYZ2017$ sbt new sbt/scala-seed.g8
[info] Loading settings from plugins.sbt ...
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/XYZ2017/.sbt/1.0/plugins
[info] Set current project to ideaprojects (in build file:/Users/XYZ2017/IdeaProjects/)

A minimal Scala project. 
name [Scala Seed Project]: hello

Template applied in ./hello

HOSTPC:IdeaProjects XYZ2017$ ls
hello

HOSTPC:IdeaProjects XYZ2017$ cd hello/

HOSTPC:hello XYZ2017$ sbt
[info] Loading settings from plugins.sbt ...
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/XYZ2017/.sbt/1.0/plugins
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/XYZ2017/IdeaProjects/hello/project
[info] Updating {file:/Users/XYZ2017/IdeaProjects/hello/project/}hello-build...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /Users/XYZ2017/IdeaProjects/hello/project/target/scala-2.12/sbt-1.0/classes ...
[info] Done compiling.
```

Comment: When you just run `sbt`, you are supposed to get an interactive prompt, where you can enter [commands](http://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Command-Line-Reference.html). Also the compiling message you see it just about loading the project definition. Try running `sbt compile`, it will compile the sources and exit.